# Resource Server responses Status 203 "Non-Authoritative Information" when GET request not executed by browser (e.g. HttpClient, Postman)

Tags: cors, authorization, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient, azure-devops-rest-api

I created an asp.net core (.Net 6) hosted Blazor WebAssembly app from scratch. I added the asp.Net Core authentication and authorisation middleware in the server app. After authentication via OpenIdConnect via AzureAD (got my access_token and cookies are set) i can call my aspNetCore Controller, that does a simple authentication check and redirects me to the resource server (DevOps REST API) then. The API responses with the desired JSON, so **everthing is fine in this flow**.

The only thing I want to change now is to start the request by button mouseclick on my WASM app. Therefore I am triggering the **GET in the code-behind by the HttpClient** class. Everything else stays the same. But in this case I get a **203 "Non-Authoritative Information"** Http Response and as content a html page.

The controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("/devops")]
[Authorize]
public class DevOpsController : ControllerBase {

    [HttpGet("repositories")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetRepositories() {
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return Redirect(
              "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1"
            );
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

1. Added generous CORS config:

```cs
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());
```

2. Set a breakpoint in my controller to compare the browser request header object with the HttpClient request headers. Tried to add or edit headers manually in the HttpClient request so i fits the browser request best, but could not adjust all of them. Marked by yellow colors are the remaining differences in the headers.

[image: Browser request headers]

[image: HttpClient request headers]

3. Checked Stack Overflow topics, but mostly people have authorization issued using a PAT